# Raid won't mount on boot after reinstall

Tags: raid, automount, mdadm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MDADM Superblock Recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69086/mdadm-superblock-recovery)

So I was having a lot of trouble with Ubuntu after upgrading to 11.10. I decided to do a clean install, and things seem to be much better. However, I am unable to get my RAID to mount after installing `mdadm`. I'm able to go to `/media`, and then mount it, but it used to mount on boot. Trying to edit `fstab`, but when I `fdisk -l`, I'm getting

> Disk /dev/md127 doesn't have a valid partition table.

When I made the array, I gave it a .ext4 partition table, and thought it was taken care of. Please help! If I run .ext4 again, I don't want it to erase the data currently on the array.

`sudo fdisk -l`

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 80.0 GB, 80025280000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 9729 cylinders, total 156299375 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   156299374    78149687   ee  GPT

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000412f6

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              63  3907024064  1953512001   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0005cf54

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1              63  3907024064  1953512001   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdd: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000a563b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1              63  3907024064  1953512001   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sde: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00088e1f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1              63  3907024064  1953512001   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdf: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000a104e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdf1              63  3907024064  1953512001   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdg: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000271fa

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdg1              63  3907024064  1953512001   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md127: 10002.0 GB, 10001973248000 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, -1853079296 cylinders, total 19535104000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 1048576 bytes / 5242880 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md127 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Comment: take a look a this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1855708